# Android ListView with Two text and One CheckBox (eg. like a Setting)

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

I'm creating Setting Activity which include two TextView and One CheckBox on right side. I have already done ListView. I want to be like when click on item and then check the CheckBox and again click on item then unchecked the CheckBox. How to implement CheckBox status?

My Code.

MainActivity.java

```
mport android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ListView list;
    String[] title = {
            "Google Plus",
            "Twitter",
            "Windows",
            "Bing",
            "Itunes",
            "Wordpress",
            "Drupal"
    };
    String[] descr = {
            "Social Network",
            "Social Network",
            "OS",
            "Search Engine",
            "Music",
            "Blog/Framework",
            "CMS"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, title, descr);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
                if (checkBox.isChecked()){
                    checkBox.setChecked(false);
                }else {
                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
                }

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + title[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

    private class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Activity context;
        private final String[] title;
        private final String[] descr;


        public CustomList(Activity context,
                          String[] title, String[] descr) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_item, title);
            this.context = context;
            this.title = title;
            this.descr = descr;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);
            final TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            TextView txtDescr = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_descr);
//            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            txtTitle.setText(title[position]);
            txtDescr.setText(descr[position]);

            return rowView;
        }

    }
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="name"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_descr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_title" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: First I assume your code is running fine till now right? No crash?

Comment: @AlanDeep yes, no crash. but when i click on text item checkbox status doesn't change. I want to do checkbox status change when click on list item. Thanks

Comment: refer this tutorial.It might help you http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

Comment: @NaingLin See my answer, I think is what you looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in onItemClick just do this:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkBox.toggle();  
    }
```

However, there's a problem here, that when you scroll up and the row is no more visible, the checkbox will restore its initial state. This is why you'll have to create your own ArrayAdapter having a generic type of MyItemInfo. That's a class where you put the 3 information you have : the state of the checkbox, and the 2 String ( TextView1, TextView2).

Method 2: (Easier)

Just create a third boolean array called state[] and put it in the constructor , in this array you update the state of the checkboxes. Of course the initial states of this array will be false, which means, after initializing, declare the values in the array state[] to false by calling: `Arrays.fill(state,false);` in the constructor.

Please make sure you don't call the 'CustomAdapter' everytime you click, as we don't want to lose the old states of the checkboxes.

Method 2 (As requested)

1) add an instance variable to your `CustomList`
boolean[] states;

2) change the constructor to be able to get the parameter states:
    `states = new boolean[7];` //by default they are false

```
 CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, title, descr,states);
```

3) add a listener to the checkbox in getView:

```
onCheckedChanged(){
states[position] = checkBox.isChecked();
}
```

And keep the previous code in onItemClick so that whenever you click on the item, the checkbox toggles its state from true to false or vice versa, and whenever a change of state occurs, you will notify the array of boolean (states).

4) in getView, please also add this line:
`checkBox.setChecked(states[position]);` 
after `textView.setText(..)` or before .

Before the last step ( step 4) if you check the first item and scroll down, and then scroll up, the item will be unchecked again. You won't notice this unless you have a long list, however, to avoid this problem, at each time the view is recreated, you want to set the `CheckBox` state to be the same as the up to date `state[]` `boolean` array. Thanks @Jitu

Comment: Thanks. Your code is working. But it doesn't when i click again i mean doesn't unchecked. i customize myself. This checkbox status will save through sharepreferences. is it good idea? Do you have any opinion?

Comment: yes it's a good idea to save in SharedPreferences the states because they are dynamic. So you can implement the coding inside the onCheckedChanged method in getView as well.

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by @Alan Deep will work no doubt but when you will scroll the list the selection value may changes depending on the call to getView() method. Set a flag to the list item whether it is checked or not, and check that flag condition in getView() method.

Comment: true so he needs to add in getView, checkBox.setChecked(states[position]); only without the flag. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                CheckBox selected = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
                Boolean checked = ((CheckBox) selected).isChecked();
                selected.setChecked(!checked);
            }
        });
```

Here what we do is...we get the the whole view on this item click event and from that view we extract check box as "selected". Now we find its current state and if its already check we uncheck it and vice versa. I hope its helpful.

Comment: please provide some explanation as well